# How to export event viewer errors to Excel in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, eventviewer

How would I export errors of event viewer from Application and Security section to excel, it has any way to export in event viewer or I must use windows powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell can export to csv, you could import it in Excel after.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Export-Csv output.csv
```

Or use [Export-XLSX PowerShell generate real Excel XLSX files without Excel and COM](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035) The rating seem good on it, thus look like correct.

> Export-XLSX Export PowerShell Objects to Excel .xlsx file without
>   Excel! These script cmdlet creates a Excel XLSX workbook file and
>   stores the data of the objects that you submit in a worksheet within
>   the workbook. You can use this script like the Export-CSV cmdlet.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're asking for the more manual way. You can filter your Application or Security Log the way you want it to be exported (IE only show Errors, or for a specific time frame) then if you right click the Application log, you choose Save Filtered Log as. Choose CVS to open it in Excel.

As @yagmoth555 pointed out. To export Error logs for the Application folder using powershell (this is easier and more automated) you could use

```
Get-Eventlog -logname Application -EntryType Error | Export-Csv output.csv
```

Obvious cat says to change to security logs change the `-logname` to `Security`

Answer (score 2):

Windows event viewer lets you backup event logs.  In Event Viewer – “Save all event as” and you should save them into evtx format. However, it doesn’t allow you to backup an event log from a remote server. For that i will recommend EventLogXP. Read this http://eventlogxp.com/blog/automating-event-log-backup/